# XCode 8 enlarges views into ScrollView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, beta, ios10

I'm not a fan of XCode's betas; I did want to try the one for XCode 8 though. However, one weird issue I'm having is that once I've opened my 7.3 project, the Storyboard enlarges all of my views into a ScrollView towards the right side--as the screenshot below shows:

[image]

I don't use Autolayout, because most of the time I set my views in specific positions.

The contains ScrollView of those 2 controllers is 320, so it doesn't get resized, only the views inside of it.

Do you think the release version of XCode 8 will fix this issue?

Or have you encountered the same problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you file a bug with Apple? Finding problems like this is sorta the point of having a public beta.

Comment: No i didn't yet, but I will. Just wanted to know if somebody else has go the same issue

Comment: A collegue just had this problem with Xcode 8 GM. We still don't have any solution :/

Comment: later tonight we'll install the official release of Xcode 8, hopefully that bug will be fixed

Comment: hum... do you have "Autoresize Subviews" checked of all your fields superviews (in inspector, just below clip subviews) ?

Comment: we tried both options, checked and unchecked, same bad result every time you reopen your project

Comment: I had the same issue with the scroll view .View looks diff when we run app in iphone 5 with ios 10. rather than view in iphone 5 having ios 9.3

Comment: may you post a screenshot of your issue? it may be helpful here

Comment: I had same problem with Xcode 8 GM.Does any one found solution?

Comment: Not yet, Apple has not released an update for Xcode 8, not even the official version, it still has that serious bug :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed on XCode 8.1, finally Apple did something good :)

Answer (score 1):

In the StoryBoard, select your ViewController. Open its sizeInspector, set the SimulatedSize to "freeform" and then select the size you want. 
Hope that helped.

Comment: for Autolayout yes, but not without it, it's an Apple bug, hopefully they'll fix it with Xcode 8.1